# unsaved warning on back pressed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show dialog when user press back or quit from fragment if there are some data unsaved. I am trying to override onbackpressed but unfortunately I got error `lateinit property barcodeList has not been initialized`. how to solve it?

here is my script on activity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val theFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    for(i in 0 until theFragment.size)
    {
        if(theFragment[i].tag == "stocker_fragment")
        {
            StockerFragment().onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

and this is in fragment:

```
fun onBackPressed() {
    var check = false
     // this barcodeList variable error.
    for(i in 0 until barcodeList.size)
    {
        if(barcodeList[i].barcode.trim()=="")
        {
            check = true
            break
        }
    }

    if (check)
    {
        AlertHelper(context).onBackPressedAlert()
    }
}
```

FYI: I have initialized barcodeList on onCreateView and everything is fine. only error in onBackPressed.

And my last question is, how do i know if user quit from fragment without pressing back button?

Comment: so whats your problem here ??

Comment: just add an else part..in the activitys back pressed

Comment: are you sure? the error is about variable has not been onitialized yet.

Comment: idk kotlin but in java the logic should be like this in activity back pressed...if unsaved show dialog else `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `onBackPressed()` implementation in the Activity. With the line `StockerFragment().onBackPressed()` you are creating a new instance of the StockerFragment and calling onBackPressed() on it, rather than calling it on the instance that is actively being used.

You should be able to adjust your Activity onBackPressed() like so:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val theFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    for(i in 0 until theFragment.size)
    {
        if(theFragment[i].tag == "stocker_fragment")
        {
            (theFragment[i] as StockerFragment).onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make this a bit more kotliny like so:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach { fragment ->
        if (fragment is StockerFragment) {
            fragment.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably also want to figure out a way to decide whether the fragment's onBackPressed has determined that the Activity should stick around or not. Then, if the fragment is happy, you should call `super.onBackPressed()` in the Activity so that the expected back behavior (leave the Activity) happens.

Comment: it works! how about my second question? how do i know if user quit from fragment from another way like pressing menu to another fragment?

Comment: Best you can do is to pay attention the fragment's lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle